# Нужно, чтобы css стили менялись с url

Tags: joomla, php, css

Здравствуйте! Мне необходимо скрыть некоторые блоки на определенных страницах. Пробовала сделать так:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/animatori/') { ?>
<style>
#news {display:none;}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Но ничего не получается.

Пробовала так:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/animatori/') echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; { ?>
<style>
#news {display:none;}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

Блоки исчезают на всех страницах. Сайт на джумле.

Comment: Маловато информации что бы что-то определенное сказать. Все что могу сказать так это проверить действительно ли 
            $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=='/animatori/'

Comment: @Регина, проверьте, что вообще содержится в `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Я с джумлой не знаком, возможно, она подменяет значение (`$_SERVER` - такой же массив, как и любой другой).

Comment: Спасибо,  тоже думала об этом, посмотрю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашла, дело было в одинарных запятых. Нужно было так

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php/detskie-prazdniki/animatori")
{
?>
<style>
#news {display:none;}
</style>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите что бы в ваших скрываемых блоках не было нечего важного. Так как ваш вариант легко обойти.

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php/detskie-prazdniki/animatori") { ?> 
<style>
news {display:none;}
</style> 
<?php } ?>
```

Да и очень плохо так делать.

Лучше сделать так

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/index.php/detskie-prazdniki/animatori") { ?> 
//тут блок который нужно срыть, на той странице
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Если использовать ваш вариант то нужно писать не равно

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/index.php/detskie-prazdniki/animatori"